# Force image to maintain native height when width changes

Tags: html, css, image

https://jsfiddle.net/q97jn9jp/

I've got some image, but **I don't** know it's `width` or `height`. I want it to be `100%` wide, but **I want it's height to stay natural** (if image height was `100px` I want it always to stay `100px`).

Is that possible?

**I don't want to use javascript.**

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  //height: ???;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
```

Comment: Are you trying to maintain the aspect ratio? or are you trying to skew them on purpose?

Comment: Do you have a way of setting the height explicitly in the markup? i.e. `<img src="" height="100" />`

Comment: @zgood - no, I dont want to mantain aspect ratio at all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realize that the goal here is to not have to use image-specific styling. If this limitation only applies to dimensions, though, this might work:

```css
.stretchy {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/100x100);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.stretchy img {
  display: block; /* eliminates descender space inherent with inline elements */
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="stretchy">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="">
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aoj31caf/1)

Comment: A very clever solution, hopefully it works for OP's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

### Not possible with pure CSS and traditional image

CSS doesn't provide any mechanism for declaring an image's natural height or width as a value.

It is not possible to do what you are asking without using JavaScript or [changing your markup and using background-image as suggested by @isherwood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931612/force-image-to-maintain-native-height-when-width-changes/34931813#34932116).

The closest you can come to what you are asking is to know the image height in advance.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/900x100" /><br />
<img src="https://placehold.it/450x100" /><br />
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" />
```

***But you can use JavaScript*** (even though you don't want to) to set the height dynamically on page load. Example with jQuery:

```js
$(function () {
  $('img').each(function () {
    var $this  = $(this),
        height = $this.height();
    $this.css({
        width : "100%",
        height: height
    });
  });
});
```

```css
/* Ensure images load in natural sizes initially */
img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://placehold.it/900x100" /><br />
<img src="https://placehold.it/450x100" /><br />
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to keep it's height, setting width to 100% without javascript.

Comment: That would damn weird. I hope it's not true.

Comment: It is man, but maybe you could do what you want adding this images by `background-image`  css property. 

check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Scaling_background_images

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep image's proportions you have to use:

```css
height: auto;
```

Comment: OP specifically mentioned disregarding proportion.

Answer (score -2):

You want a responsive image class that automatically resizes your image to the width of the viewport and dynamically changes it's height.

```
.image-responsive {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

The key is to make the image a block level element with an automatically determined height while limiting the width to 100% of the available column.

Comment: OP wants 100% width, not a limit.

Answer (score -2):

Edit: Sorry, I misread that you didn't know the height once I started looking at the fiddle. I went based off of that image.

Well first, let's explain how the % works.

When sizing something by a % it will essentially 'fill' it's container. You can see how that works in the fiddle you supplied by dragging the middle divider to different sizes.

In this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q97jn9jp/3/

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

You can see that the image height stays 100px, or it's natural height as you explained. While the width stretches to fill the containers width.

Likewise, if you don't include a height, it will scale with the width, which is what you are experiencing in your fiddle.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: He doesn't know the height of the image. It can be anything. Hard-coding it to be 100px isn't an option.

Comment: Ohh my bad, I misread that. I was going based off of the image provided.